# Add new row with jQuery, calculation function not executed

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that has this function:

```
function subtotal(){
        var gt = 0;
        $('.itemlist tr').each(function (){
            $(this).find('.ttl span').html($('.qty', this).val() * $('.price span', this).text());
        });
        $('.ttl').each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
        });
        $('.subtotal').html(total);         
    }       
    $(".qty").keyup(subtotal);
```

But having added a new row with this function;

```
$(".addrow a").click(function(event){
        $(".itemlist").append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="delRow">x</a></td><td>000000</td><td><select class="fixed2"><option>---</option><option>Baju Kurung</option><option>Kebaya Pondan Shining</option></select></td><td><select class="fixed2"><option>---</option><option>Hijau</option><option>Purple</option></select></td><td>0</td><td><input type="number" class="qty" /></td><td class="price">RM<span>2.00</span></td><td class="ttl">0.00</td></tr>');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

The newly created row isn't functioning properly anymore.

Here's http://jsfiddle.net/RtCdG/3/

Help and feedback appreciated.

Comment: The answer is event deleg... ah forgot what it's called :/

Comment: hahaha :).... delegation i guess.. ;)

Comment: That might just be it ;)

Comment: and where actaully is your `.subtotal` element ??

Comment: Where's the answer? The jsfiddle I given is having the problem. My subtotal element is missing in the fiddle, let me update it. http://jsfiddle.net/RtCdG/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code for you,

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".qty", function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.ttl span').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.qty').val() * $(this).closest('tr').find('.price span').text());
    $('.ttl span').each(function () {            
        total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    });
    $('.subtotal').html(total);
});
```

and your new insertinf html should have `<td class="ttl">RM<span>0.00</span></td>` instead of `<td class="ttl">0.00</td>`

http://jsfiddle.net/RtCdG/9/

Update,

As you request following are the reasons,

1. To apply any event to dynamic content, you have to use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API
2. You are calling`.find('.ttl span').html()` in your `subtotal` but there is no `span` inside the `.ttl` for new row.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. You've been great. If you don't mind, can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep my mind .on dynamically from now. And I missed that span for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the `keyup` handler to the existing rows. When you added the new row the `keyup` handler isn't added automatically.

You need to delegate the event from a container object with

```
$("#container").on("keyup", function(){ 
    // do your keyup stuff here
 });
```

(`#container` is some DOM element - probably the containing `<table>`)

Done this way the `keyup` handler will operate on all rows you have now and any you add in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have develop plugin to help building calculation form using jquery, try this if it help you reduce your headache

http://www.xsanisty.com/calx/

implementation sample that similar to your case can be found here

http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/calx_with_dynamic_form.html